# Other Classes onClick ImageView

Tags: android

I have a problem. So I have few activities, in one of the activities I have 6 ImageView and I've set for everyone a "onClick" from xml. I am wondering how to check if an image was clicked and then appear it in another acitivty. Here is what I've wrote, it's not even done, have I did it good? If yes, can you help me with "importing" this images to the final activity?

```
public ImageView imageSelected;
private Intent i = new Intent(this, MemeSecondStep.class);

public void onFirstPicClick(View view) {
        startActivity(i);
        imageSelected = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.goitiPunu);
    }

    public void onSecondPicClick(View view) {
        startActivity(i);
        imageSelected = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.goitiPdoi);
    }

    public void onThirdPicClick(View view) {
        startActivity(i);
        imageSelected = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.goitiPtrei);
    }

    public void onFourthPicClick(View view) {
        startActivity(i);
        imageSelected = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.goitiPpatru);
    }

    public void onFifthPicClick(View view) {
        startActivity(i);
        imageSelected = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.goitiPcinci);
    }

    public void onSixthPicClick(View view) {
        startActivity(i);
        imageSelected = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.goitiPsase);
    }
```

Comment: You would need an ImageView in the layout of the next Activity and set the sources the same. You can't simply "move" an ImageView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a image that you click in intent and get it to other activity like this.

```
public ImageView imageSelected;
private Intent i = new Intent(this, MemeSecondStep.class);

public void onFirstPicClick(View view) {
        i.putExtra("firstImageKey","firstImage");
        startActivity(i);
        imageSelected = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.goitiPunu);
    }
```

And in you second activity must have a ImageView and when you get from intent which image you click set the source of image what you want.

With this lines you can get extra from intent and set desire image

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 String clickedImageName = intent.getStringExtra("firstImageKey");
 if(clickedImageName.equals("firstImage"){
  //set desire image
 }
```

There are many solution for your case but this is the first which come to my mind.

**UPDATE**

Here the second solution that can solve your problem:

First in your xml with six imageViews you must set tag to every one of them like this.

**first_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:tag="image1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:tag="image2"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:tag="image3"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:tag="image4"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView4"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:tag="image5"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView5"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:tag="image6"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in your MainActivity(Your activity with six images) declare all image views, implement `View.OnClickListener` to your class  and set all images onClick listeners.After that in `onClick()` method implement logic like when you click first image make intent to second activity and pass image tag to intent. All actions may represend like this.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ImageView image1;
    private ImageView image2;
    private ImageView image3;
    private ImageView image4;
    private ImageView image5;
    private ImageView image6;
    private String yourImageTag="";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initializeLayoutElements();

        image1.setOnClickListener(this);
        image2.setOnClickListener(this);
        image3.setOnClickListener(this);
        image4.setOnClickListener(this);
        image5.setOnClickListener(this);
        image6.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void initializeLayoutElements(){
        image1= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        image2= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        image3= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        image4= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        image5= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
        image6= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        yourImageTag = v.getTag().toString();
        intent.putExtra("imageTag",yourImageTag);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Then when you make intent successfully, get extra from it in SecondActivity and according to which image you click from first activity set desire image source to your imageView in SecondActivity like this.

**SecondActivity.java**

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private ImageView yourNewImage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        initializeLayoutElements();
        getDataFromIntent();

    }

    private void initializeLayoutElements(){
        yourNewImage= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    }

    private void getDataFromIntent(){
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String yourImageTag = intent.getStringExtra("imageTag");
        switch (yourImageTag){
            case "image1":
                Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "image1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Here you can set your desire recourse for yourNewImage
                break;
            case "image2":
                Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "image2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Here you can set your desire recourse for yourNewImage
                break;
            case "image3":
                Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "image3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Here you can set your desire recourse for yourNewImage
                break;
            case "image4":
                Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "image4", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Here you can set your desire recourse for yourNewImage
                break;
            case "image5":
                Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "image5", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Here you can set your desire recourse for yourNewImage
                break;
            case "image6":
                Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "image6", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Here you can set your desire recourse for yourNewImage
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

xml for second activity look like this.

**activity_second.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

but this is only for your test case you must change it. Hope this update help you!

Comment: Hey, I have a question, if I change "firstImage" with R.id.goitiPunu is ok?

Comment: no i think its not a problem but if you do this you must check for R.id.gotiPunu in second activity fo equality

Comment: try it and let me know what happaned ok?

Comment: Are you sure it's intent.getExtra on the second activity? I get getExtra with red if I put that.

Comment: Yep if you put string in first activity you must get with getStringExtra().. if you put int must get with getInt()

Comment: check my edit answer sorry my mistake not getExtra() correct is getStringExtra()

Comment: Even though I've editet the intent declaration and set it to public.

Comment: hmm i dont see error wiith this image can you post your code now, you can do this with edit your old post

Comment: I think the whole problem is at the line 15 as it says both to your code and to other guy code. My 15th line is: private Intent i = new Intent(this, Settings.class);

Comment: i dont think that here has a problem. If your intent is succsess etc. did you move from first activity to second without error

Comment: Hey, i have to go, I am gonna be back tomorow, ok?

Comment: i update my answer when you are here you can check it !

Comment: Man it does works, I had a problem on my own but I've resolved it, God Bless! Thanks for all the time you've spent on me!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Please upload completed photo.

Please use click="onImageClick" in xml.

```
public ImageView imageSelected;
//if you use R.drawabel.logo in code or @drawable/logo in xml.
private int resid = 0;

public void onImageClick(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MemeSecondStep.class);
    switch(view.getId()){
       case R.id.goitiPunu:
       //if you use @drawable/goitiPunu in layout.
       resid = R.drawable.goitiPunu;
       break
       case R.id.goitiPdoi:
       break
    }
    i.putExtra("resid",resid);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

MemeSecondStep.java

```
private void onCreate(Some params){
    int resid = getIntent().getIntegerExtra("resid",0);
    imageView.setImageResource(resid).
}
```

Comment: Dude, my app crashed when I do your solution. This is the error I get:

Comment: I've posted an image 1 comment up.

Comment: The image is not completed and the area cropped is important.Provide error log if posssible.